# Locate elements inside WebView

Tags: detox

I'm trying to automate a test with detox. The app under test is implemented using react-native but we have a screen that renders a WebView that load an url. In this case, I cannot use the accessibilityLabel or testID in order to access the elements displayed inside the WebView. Anyone know if there is a way to locate elements inside a WebView with detox?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do so https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/665

A work around could be done by using this but if running on different screen sizes the test would probably fail https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/334#issuecomment-335802212

Answer (score 0):

It's finally possible to interact with webview elements in Detox (only Android currently).

Check out this [link](https://medium.com/tenets/detox-webview-tests-are-a-reality-39539dfe055)

Comment: It does not work either in android. It needs to find the Native matcher in AndroidExpectation class.