# bypassing webviews in detox

Tags: react-native, testing, automation, detox

My login component is a webview, so while I am trying to test my app my application won't go further than the login component since detox has no control over webviews. Any way I can work this out. I want to find a way by which I can test other components of my application. I can skip the webview component, but I want my automated test to go forward.

Comment: Detox doesn't support WebView, more information here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461368/locate-elements-inside-webview>